# Add URL Parameter depending on Cookie-Value

Tags: .htaccess, url, cookies, parameters, query-string

I am working on a WordPress plugin that shows Gutenberg blocks depending on user categories. For instance: If a user has the category "winter", blocks with the category "winter" are shown and blocks with the category "summer" are NOT shown - vice versa.

I store the user clicks in a cookie ("user-data"). This cookie is set via JS and modified on every page load via ajax. A second cookie ("user-cat") contains the ID of the estimated user category.

I use WP Rocket for caching. Unfortunately WP Rocket stores the pages as static content and that's why the PHP rendering of the Gutenberg blocks isn't dynamic.

Because of that I would like to add the current user category as a parameter to the URL. If a user has the category "winter" with the ID 10, the URL should look like this: [www.mydomain.com?x=10](http://www.mydomain.com?x=10). That way WP Rocket creates different static versions of each page.

Following pages would be stored separately by WP Rocket:

- [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
- [www.mydomain.com?x=10](http://www.mydomain.com?x=10)
- [www.mydomain.com?x=100](http://www.mydomain.com?x=100)

I tried to achieve this by modifying the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/wp-login.*|/wp-admin)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !x [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user-cat=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?x=%1 [NC,QSA,R,L]
```

This solution works fine on standard WordPress pages, but it seems hacky to me and does not work on multisite installations. I would like to use proper WordPress code and not edit the .htaccess manually.

Is there any other/better way to achieve this? Does anyone have a better idea how to create dynamic Gutenberg blocks when using caching plugins?

Comment: _"I would like to use proper WordPress code and not edit the .htaccess manually."_ - then you should go look into `add_rewrite_rule`, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250837/understanding-add-rewrite-rule That is for rewriting based on the URL path only though, you won't be able to wrangle the cookie into this with that. But then the cookie can completely be dispensed with anyway, if you are transporting the relevant info via the URL now.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @CBroe! I already looked into `add_rewrite_rule` but I don't really understand how this would help me with my problem. I think that i have to use the cookie. Maybe my explanation wasn't good enough but the URL parameter 'x' has to change depending on the cookie data.

Comment: You would use this to set up a route, so that you can access not only `/somepage`, but also `/somepage/100`, and then can access the `100` as a parameter.

Comment: And in the place where you currently let the user click something to set a cookie, you instead provide them with the different links to access either `/somepage`, `/somepage/10` or `/somepage/100` directly.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Maybe I didn't explain the way the cookie is set good enough.

The cookie with the user data looks like this:
`{
"clicks":{
"22":2,
"23":3,
"24":1
},
"user_category": 22
}`

It contains an array with the clicks and the user category (category with most clicks). The clicks are increased via JS and ajax when the user visits a page, wich has a category (the page category is set in de WordPress backend and saved as a meta field of the page). So there is no link that is clicked by the user and that could be used to set a different link.

Comment: But what does the counting of the clicks have to do with dynamically showing the blocks, based on the user's category? The user's category does not change, does it? So why would you need the info from the cookie in the URL now for caching purposes?

Comment: The user's category only changes if the click count of an other category is higher than the current category.

The blocks on the page check via PHP if the user category in the cookie and the block category are the same. If they are the same, the block is rendered. Without caching this works perfectly.

The caching Plugin WP Rocket caches the pages as **static** content. So the PHP isn't executed and the block can never really check the user category. So i tried to use the url parameter to create different variations of the static pages. That's the only purpose of the url parameter.

Comment: But the user would still have to _get to_ those different versions of the page somehow. If you are not planing on providing them with direct links, then how did you intend to handle that part then? If you have _one_ link that leads the user to this page - then you could manipulate the href of that client-side via JS, based on what counter values or category is currently stored in your cookie ...

Comment: Or, if the info you do not want to show to the user is not that sensitive that it would be a catastrophe if anyone was ever able to "find" it on their own by checking the page source - you could simply output _all_ blocks (and have that output cached as a whole, as-is), and then handle the showing/hiding of specific blocks on the client side, via JavaScript.

Comment: Manipulating the links via JS is the only solution I've come up with so far. I have tried it and it works. But I thought there was a better way to do this via .htaccess.

Comment: The problem with the JS solution is that this only works when the second page is called. When the user calls the start page (example.com), the content is not yet dynamic and always stays the same for every user.

Comment: For me, this is not a problem if the user can find out his category. But showing/hiding blocks via CSS/JS on the client side could generate unnecessarily long source code.

Also, if the dynamic block is a header slider, this could lead to layout shifts and would  affect the page load time.

Comment: _"The problem with the JS solution is that this only works when the second page is called."_ - why? (And _what_ "second page" to begin with, your description of what is actually supposed to happen when & where, is still rather unclear ...)

Comment: I could manipulate the href of the internal links and add the "?x=user_cat" parameter to the href via JS. That's what you meant, right? This would work for all pages but not for the first visited page (landing page). The landing page would always be static because the url doesn't contain the "?x=user_cat" url parameter.

Comment: So make the landing page itself only check the user category, and have it _automatically redirect_ to the correct `?x=user_cat` URL then ...?